# How can I use props, $ref and $emit in Vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I've been learning Vuejs with Vue-cli.

I'm trying to figure out how `props` and `$emit` work.

One thing I can't figure out is that how do I handle with `function` related to sevral components.

`All`,`Ongoing`, `Done` buttons are supposed to filter list depend on each checkbox value and its color changes to green when active.

I don't know where to put `filteredTodos() {}` stuff which currently I added in `ListTodo.vue`, since those are related in both of `Swichers.vue` and `ListTodo.vue`.

My code is: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqyob?file=/src/App.vue)

If somebody knows, could you tell me how?

Thanks

Comment: I think you've got it! Uncomment your `data` item in App, and uncomment the `prop` in ListToDo. The only thing left to do is pass the prop down to the ListTodo... `<ListToDo :filtered="filtered />`

Comment: Also, it appears that the `filtered` prop should be a String, not an Object, based on what you're emitting in Switchers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I followed your way and needed to add `filterState: this.filtered` to escape from overwrite props.
However, still not solved yet.
I updated a question and code.
Please take a look if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be more in this spirit of vuejs to avoid refs and having state in child components.

The app contains the items and the filter and the todolist.vue binds a props to a filtered list (computed property).
The switcher takes a v-model on the filter (two way binding). 
Remove all is passed as a callback property.

(Edit)

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>TODO</h1>
    <input type="text" v-model="inputTask" placeholder="Enter your task">
    <button @click="addTask">Add task</button>

    <Switchers
      v-model='filter'
      :onRemoveAll="removeAllItem"
    />
    <ListTodo :todos='filtered' :noTask='noTask' :onRemoveTask='removeTask' :onToggleStatus='toggleStatus' />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Switchers from "./components/Switchers";
import ListTodo from "./components/ListTodo";

export default {
  keyName: 'myTodoList',
  components: {
    Switchers,
    ListTodo,
  },

  created() {
    let keyObject =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.keyName))
    if (keyObject) {
      this.todos = keyObject;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputTask: '',
      // filtered:'',
      filter: 'all',


      todos: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filtered() {
      this.filter; this.todos;
      return this.filteredTodos()
    },
    id() { return this.todos.length+1 },
    noTask() {
      return {
        'all': 'No tasks',
        'ongoing': 'No ongoing tasks',
        'done': 'No done tasks',
      }[this.filter]
    },
  },
  methods: {
    addTask() {
      if (this.inputTask==='') {
        return
      }
      this.addTaskChild(this.inputTask);
      this.inputTask=''
    },
    addTaskChild(inputValue) {
      const todo = {id: this.id, task:inputValue, done:false}
      this.todos.push(todo)
      localStorage.setItem(this.keyName, JSON.stringify(this.todos));
      this.filter = 'all'
    },

    removeAllItem() {
      this.todos = []
      localStorage.clear();
      this.filter = 'all'
    },

    filteredTodos() {
      return this.todos.filter(todo => {
        if (this.filter === 'ongoing') {
          return !todo.done;
        } else if (this.filter === 'done') {
          return todo.done;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
    },

    toggleStatus(todo) {
      todo.done =  !todo.done
      localStorage.setItem(this.keyName, JSON.stringify(this.todos));
    },

    removeTask(t) {
      this.todos = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== t.id)
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

ListTodo.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{todos.length}} tasks left /  {{todos.length}} tasks of all</p>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="todo in todos" :class="{done:todo.done}" :key="todo.id">
      <input type="checkbox" :checked="todo.done" @click="status(todo)">
      {{ todo.task }}
      <button @click="onRemoveTask(todo)">Remove task</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p v-show="todos.length===0">{{noTask}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    todos: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    onRemoveTask: {
      type: Function,
      required: true
    },
    onToggleStatus: {
      type: Function,
      required: true
    },
    noTask: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      id: 1,
      done:false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    status(todo) {
      this.onToggleStatus(todo)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Switchers.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button :class="{active: filter ==='all'}" @click="set_filter('all')">All</button>
    <button :class="{active: filter ==='ongoing'}" @click="set_filter('ongoing')">Ongoing</button>
    <button :class="{active: filter ==='done'}" @click="set_filter('done')">Done</button>
    <button @click="onRemoveAll">Remove all</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    onRemoveAll: {
      type: Function,
      required: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      handler(v) {
        if (this.filter !== v)
          this.filter = v
        },
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      filter:'',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    set_filter(f) {
      this.filter = f
      this.$emit('input', f)
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.active {background: turquoise;}

</style>
```

Idiomatic vuejs prefers reactive properties to imperative style. In this case, we would rather keep a single copy of the todo list + filter criteria (in App) and expose computed properties for the next id, filtered  list and noTask message.

`Switchers` is a pure controller component: it has no state and its only role is to translate user selection to call on the App model.

`ListTodo` is a view and only takes care of displaying the list of todos that it is given as a prop. It doesn't care about whether the list is filtered or not.

There are small style changes that could have been done too but they don't have anything to do with vuejs / emit, so I didn't do them.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-nash-t1kc3?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm pretty beginner to Vue.
I can't imagine what you say with my pore experience :(
I'll practice more!

Comment: I edited my answer with the complete source code. Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and description.
Still need some time to understand how those connects each other based on your code. I'll figure out
Thanks anyways, I appreciate that.